# Between "Expert knowledge" and "Working knowledge"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I wonder how best to describe a position between "Expert knowledge" and "Working knowledge" (as in "Expert knowledge in HTML/CSS", "Working knowledge in JavaScript"). Is there any term that suits somewhere not so expert but higher than working knowledge? "Decent knowledge" sounds fine?

Thank you in advance for your advice.

Comment: Although “decent” might be intended as “good enough but not definitive or authoritative”,“Decent knowledge” immediately makes one think of the alternative “indecent knowledge”.

Answer (score 1):

There are various possibilities: *skilled*, *talented*, *proficient* all seem to be less authoritative than *expert* but more competent than merely *working*.

I do not repeat easily found definitions of the words, whose meanings are somewhat intermingled in dictionary entries. *talented* has a greater connotation of creativity and natural ability than *skilled* or *proficient* so may be closer to *expert* than they are.

Comment: Thanks for this. Actually, "competent knowledge" sounds fine, too. Probably fits the bill well (not as good as "expert", but better than "working").